# How to set volume on mpc from cron job

Tags: python, cron, mpd

On a raspberry Pi running bookworm.  I have a python file

```
import subprocess
command = ['mpc', 'volume', '16']
subprocess.run(command, text = True,  capture_output=True)
```

which runs fine from a terminal but it I run it at boot from cron I get MPD error: Connection refused
How can I run it from cron?
The line in cron is
`@reboot /home/pi/.venv/bin/python3 /home/pi/v02_2/test_mpd.py >> /home/pi/v02_2/logs/cron.log 2>&1`

Comment: Please show your cron file

Comment: it may run as different user and not have access to your desktop to run it. maybe you should run it in `.bashrc` or `profile` to run it after you login to your desktop